# Alsa Lib PyAudio error on Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: python, bluetooth, pi-3b+

I was looking at an old question that gave advice for fixing these errors:

> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> connect(2) call to /tmp/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
> attempt to connect to server failed

It said to do the following for my default bluetooth device:

> $ cat ~/.asoundrc
>
> defaults.bluealsa.interface "hci0"
>
> defaults.bluealsa.device "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
>
> defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
>
> defaults.bluealsa.delay 10000

The problem is, I'm not using any Bluetooth devices. I have a USB mic plugged in I'm trying to use. I put in some dummy information, but now I'm getting the following errors:

> Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
>
> ALSA lib bluealsa-pcm.c:649:(_snd_pcm_bluealsa_open) Invalid BT device address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>
> ALSA lib bluealsa-pcm.c:649:(_snd_pcm_bluealsa_open) Invalid BT device address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>
> Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924

Is there any way to simply tell pyaudio I don't want to use any Bluetooth?

I'm sorry if this is not the proper way to ask this followup question but it said I didn't have enough reputation to post a comment.

My program runs fine but I'd like to get rid of the error/warning messages since it makes finding my output more cumbersome.

Thanks so much.